# How can I create a array using the random function whose sum is 1 in python using nympy?

Tags: python, numpy, random

Working on an assignment which requires me to create an array with random numbers whose sum is 1.

The actual problem statement looks something like this :

```
get_initial_weights

This function should have one parameter, an integer m. This function should return a matrix with 1
row and m columns containing random values, each between zero and one. The sum of these m
values should be equal to one.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.random` to create your matrix of size `(1,m)`, and then divide it by the sum of the array to normalize the sum to 1.

```
t = np.random.random((1,m))
t = t / t.sum()
```